# Limit of a sequence that arises from product

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$
such that

1. $(x_n)$ converges to $\bar{x}$ and
2. for every $n$ we have $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle=0$.

Is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle\bar{x},y_n\rangle=0$?

Comment: For $d\geq 2$, take $x_n=(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n},1,0,...,0)$ and $y_n=(n,-n(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}),0,...,0)$. Then $\overline{x}=(1,1,0,...,0)$. But $\langle\overline{x},y_n\rangle=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: For $d=1$ is it true. If $x_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$ then $\overline{x}=0$ and the last limit holds. If $x_n$ is eventually different from zero. Then $y_n$ is eventually zero, and the last limit holds.